# Blackberry java valid directories

Tags: java, blackberry-jde

Is there a way in Blackberry Java (5.0 and later) getting the the valid directories? Like for instance, the home directory is "file:///store/home/user/", is there any method like getHomeDirectory() and will return that path?

If none, would the hard-coded path can be applied to all version of Blackberry Java?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

> The **System** class maintains a **Properties** object that describes the configuration of the current working environment. System properties include information about the current user, the current version of the Java runtime, and the character used to separate components of a file path name.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

Comment: It returns null. I am using a simulator. But, regardless, I need to get valid directories. Thanks for your response, btw.

Comment: If you are using a **simulator** I'm not suprised you are getting null.